# iptables routing on multiple virtual interfaces

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, nat, iptables-redirect

I have 1.1.1.1 outside, which is the public interface of vm1 in azure. VM1 has 192.168.1.1 an internal IP. In addition there's also 1.1.1.2 (virtual) which is attached to the same interface and is mapped respectively to 192.168.1.2 on the inside, and there're a few more like this. This is for a router, that needs to forward port 3389 (amongst others) to an external IP, which varies depending on which public ip was requested. For instance, if 1.1.1.1:3389 was requested, iptables should forward it to 2.2.2.2 on port 5000, but if 1.1.1.2:3389 was requested, ip tables should forward it to 2.2.2.3 on port 5000 and so on. I've set up the following so far:

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:5000
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 1.1.1.2 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.3:5000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
```

but it's not working.. please advise?

Comment: Do you word at Cloudflare. If not then don't use their IP address.

Comment: To route between networks, you need at least two interfaces. Remove unnecessary virtual interfaces for now, and make your life easier to troubleshoot. You just need two interfaces on VM1. Then edit your question with new details.